# System Assert Initial List Size

Tags: apex, unit-test, constructor

I have a class that has a constructor that is defining a list. I want to assert that the initial size of the list is set properly. An error is being throw when I run my test class around verifying the initial size of the list and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone see an error on my part with the below code?

```
@isTest
static void Product2Extension_UnitTest(){
    Test.startTest();
        PageReference pageRef = Page.NewVFPage;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);     
        Product2 prod = new Product2();
        prod.Name = 'Updated Name';
        prod.IsActive = true;
        ApexPages.standardController controller = new ApexPages.standardController(prod);
        NewVFPageHelper nvfph = new NewVFPageHelper(controller);        
        system.assertEquals(0, nvfph.productsToInsert.size());
    Test.stopTest();
}


public class NewVFPageHelper {
    public List<ProductWrapper> productsToInsert {get;set;}
    public NewVFPageHelper(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
        productsToInsert = new List<ProductWrapper>();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Given this code, I wouldn't expect the assertion to fail. Are you sure your code deployed successfully?

Comment: yea everything is deployed successfully. I am wondering if it could be a org issue. I am working on a trailhead module and it is throwing `Ensure you verify that the constructor sets the initial size of the productsToInsert list properly.` and I don't see how I am not verifying the list size properly

Comment: That doesn't sound like an assertion failure.  it's a trailhead failure.  What do you mean an error is thrown?  where do you see this error? maybe include a screenshot for context.

Comment: @NickCook - it is a trailhead failure but I have to assume it is a trailhead assertion failure because trailhead must run off of assertions when it checks the work done. The error message verbiage "verify" signifies to me that it is a assertion failure. I will update the post with a screen shot of the error message.

Comment: Which Trailhead module is it?